# Dockerfile for Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Spring [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) tell me how to write a Dockerfile for my Spring Boot app. I adapted it to my gradle build with "build/libs" directory

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

But in my build/libs directory there are multiple versions of my jar:

```
app-22.9.0.jar
app-22.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
app-22.10.0.jar
app-22.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
```

Of course I can call 'gradle clean assemble' to do the job. But I need the Dockerfile in a test too. It is annoying to run clean assemble all the time.

How can I  specify in my Dockerfile COPY command to use only the latest jar.

Answer (score 0):

Docker uses normal shell glob rules when expanding patterns like this; there's no way to tell it to use the single most recent matching file, or the file with the largest embedded semantic version, or other things.

When you build the image, you can pass a more specific value for that `ARG` like

```bash
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=app-22.10.0.jar -t myapp:22.10.0 .
```

You may also want that build version to be in the image tag and it may be helpful to script this.

(You probably don't need to `./gradlew clean` in between rebuilds, and that might make running `./gradlew assemble` go faster.)